# How to create '.epub' extension file using php?

Tags: php, epub

I'm building a web application which should create '.epub' extension files with the text content that exist on mysql database, I could fetch data from mysql database but unable to create '.epub' file. Is there any way to create '.epub' file using php script.

Comment: https://github.com/Grandt/PHPePub

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the content-type using `header()` and then echo out the content from your database:

```
header('Content-type: application/epub+zip');
echo $data;
```

If you need to force the browser to download the file, you can use the following:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer'); 
header('Content-Type: application/epub+zip'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mybook.epub"'); 
echo $data;
```

Comment: Note that EPUB is a ZIP archive with another extension, so if you want text from a database in an EPUB file eBook, you'd still need to create a valid ZIP file in PHP and can't just echo the text from the database.

Comment: I made use of that above code, it creates .epub file but it can't be viewed by ebook reader ( I'm using iBooks app to read .epub )

Comment: @Florian Bach can you please share any code samples to echo text from database in epub format.

Comment: Take any working ebook you have, rename it to "*.zip", open it and you see the structure. Then, create a ZIP looking the same in PHP.